# How to change port 8080 for Tomcat on macOS High Sierra?

Tags: macos, tomcat, macos-high-sierra

I installed tomcat and I executed start.sh. Tomcat started.

I checked the port 8080 with the command

```
lsof -i :8080
```

There isn't any process running in this port.

How can I know in which port is running tomcat and change this port?. I have already used the port 8080 and I need to change

EDITED
 I changed the connector por to 8081

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

I checked

```
lsof -i :8081
```

There isn't any process.

How can I check the tomcat port?

Comment: What do you see in the logs when you start tomcat? Try starting from the command line with `catalina.sh run` instead of `startup.sh` (assuming that this is what you meant by start.sh)

Answer (score 1):

You should open `conf/server.xml` and look for a `Connector` tag like:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Set the `port` attribute to the desired value and restart the server.